# UWP custom style for navigationview

Tags: c#, uwp, styles

I need to customize NavigationView like this:
[image]

I don't know how to create Textblock "Connected" inside NavigationView. I read about PaneTitle, but its not what i need at this situation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the native `NavigationView` control, what you need is to create a default style of the `NavigationView` control.

Open the DocumentOutline windows from the Visual Studio, it will show all the controls that you've added to the Xaml page, then choose the target `NavigationView`, right click it and choose **Edit Template** -> **Edit a copy**. Then the Visual Studio will automatically generate a default style of the `NavigationView`.

In the style, there is a Grid called `PaneContentGrid` inside a SplitView.Pane, that's the place where the NavigationViewItems are listed. You could add another button as you want.